# Python: How to copy all attibutes from base class to derived one

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I want to achieve the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class SuperHero(object): 
    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

class SuperMan(SuperHero): 
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sh = SuperHero()
    sh.setName("Clark Kent")
    sm = SuperMan(sh)  # This does *not* work in real python
    print sm.getName() # prints "Clark Kent"
```

Do I have to copy the attributes one by one or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't construct a `SuperMan` in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer explicit solution - copying one by one. `Martijn Pieters`'s solution is nice, but with time your `__dict__` may grow and you may not want to copy all it's content (or worse - forget about this fact and experience some nasty side effects). Besides the Zen of Python says: `Explicit is better than implicit.`.

Side note - you are aware of properties, right? So your code could be more pythonic if you used them:

```
class SuperHero(object):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self._name = name

sh = SuperHero()
sh.name = "Clark Kent"
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't use get/set methods *or* properties. Just use the attribute directly.

Comment: All depends. If there are no side effects of getters/setters, using attributes is perfectly fine (and simpler). If you want to do something else besides just getting/setting value - properties are what you shoulduse.

Comment: I did the implementation copying one by one and picking just the attributes I need. In this case really nicer than copying the whole `__dict__` including attributes I don't need.

Comment: Agreed, you follow Zen of Python well :)

Answer (score 8):

Add a initiator function that copies across the `__dict__` attribute:

```
class SuperMan(SuperHero): 
    def __init__(self, source=None):
        if source is not None:
            self.__dict__.update(source.__dict__)
```

The `__dict__` of an instance holds all instance attributes, the above merely copies over all of those attributes to the new `SuperMan` instance.

Demo:

```
>>> class SuperHero(object): 
...     def setName(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def getName(self):
...         return self.name
... 
>>> class SuperMan(SuperHero): 
...     def __init__(self, source=None):
...         if source is not None:
...             self.__dict__.update(source.__dict__)
... 
>>> sh = SuperHero()
>>> sh.setName("Clark Kent")
>>> sm = SuperMan(sh)
>>> print sm.getName() 
Clark Kent
```

Or, for a more terrible hack, you could swap out the class attribute:

```
sh = SuperHero()
sh.setName("Clark Kent")
sh.__class__ = SuperMan
```

but that can lead to more interesting bugs as you never called the `SuperMan` initializer and thus the expected state might be incorrect.